# search using xsl

Tags: xml

Helo, i am looking to do a search function in xsl to find a keyword in a xml file. I used the key function but it only find a specified word fully. Example, i want input word "com" and I want it find include "com.infopro" or any word that contain this string.

---

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE dependencies SYSTEM "http://depfind.sourceforge.net/dtd/dependencies.dtd">

<dependencies>
    <package confirmed="yes">
        <name>com.infopro.Dependency</name>
        <class confirmed="yes">
            <name>com.infopro.Dependency.A</name>
            <outbound type="class" confirmed="no">java.lang.Object</outbound>
            <outbound type="class" confirmed="no">javax.ejb.Stateless</outbound>
            <inbound type="feature" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.B.B()</inbound>
            <inbound type="feature" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.B.a</inbound>
            <feature confirmed="yes">
                <name>com.infopro.Dependency.A.A()</name>
                <outbound type="feature" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.A.b</outbound>
                <outbound type="class" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.B</outbound>
                <outbound type="feature" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.B.B()</outbound>
                <outbound type="feature" confirmed="no">java.lang.Object.Object()</outbound>
                <inbound type="feature" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.B.B()</inbound>
            </feature>
            <feature confirmed="yes">
                <name>com.infopro.Dependency.A.b</name>
                <outbound type="class" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.B</outbound>
                <inbound type="feature" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.A.A()</inbound>
            </feature>
            <feature confirmed="yes">
                <name>com.infopro.Dependency.A.check(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)</name>
                <outbound type="feature" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.A.stat</outbound>
                <outbound type="class" confirmed="no">java.lang.String</outbound>
                <inbound type="feature" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.A.doStatus()</inbound>
            </feature>
            <feature confirmed="yes">
                <name>com.infopro.Dependency.A.doStatus()</name>
                <outbound type="feature" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.A.check(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)</outbound>
                <outbound type="feature" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.A.name</outbound>
                <outbound type="feature" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.A.user_id</outbound>
                <outbound type="class" confirmed="no">java.lang.String</outbound>
            </feature>
            <feature confirmed="yes">
                <name>com.infopro.Dependency.A.name</name>
                <outbound type="class" confirmed="no">java.lang.String</outbound>
                <inbound type="feature" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.A.doStatus()</inbound>
            </feature>
            <feature confirmed="yes">
                <name>com.infopro.Dependency.A.stat</name>
                <outbound type="class" confirmed="no">java.lang.String</outbound>
                <inbound type="feature" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.A.check(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)</inbound>
            </feature>
            <feature confirmed="yes">
                <name>com.infopro.Dependency.A.user_id</name>
                <outbound type="class" confirmed="no">java.lang.String</outbound>
                <inbound type="feature" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.A.doStatus()</inbound>
            </feature>
        </class>
        <class confirmed="yes">
            <name>com.infopro.Dependency.B</name>
            <outbound type="class" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.C</outbound>
            <outbound type="class" confirmed="no">java.lang.Object</outbound>
            <outbound type="class" confirmed="no">javax.ejb.Stateless</outbound>
            <inbound type="feature" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.A.A()</inbound>
            <inbound type="feature" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.A.b</inbound>
            <feature confirmed="yes">
                <name>com.infopro.Dependency.B.B()</name>
                <outbound type="class" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.A</outbound>
                <outbound type="feature" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.A.A()</outbound>
                <outbound type="feature" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.B.a</outbound>
                <outbound type="feature" confirmed="no">java.lang.Object.Object()</outbound>
                <inbound type="feature" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.A.A()</inbound>
            </feature>
            <feature confirmed="yes">
                <name>com.infopro.Dependency.B.a</name>
                <outbound type="class" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.A</outbound>
                <inbound type="feature" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.B.B()</inbound>
            </feature>
            <feature confirmed="yes">
                <name>com.infopro.Dependency.B.check(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)</name>
                <outbound type="feature" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.B.stat</outbound>
                <outbound type="class" confirmed="no">java.lang.String</outbound>
                <inbound type="feature" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.B.doStatus()</inbound>
            </feature>
            <feature confirmed="yes">
                <name>com.infopro.Dependency.B.doStatus()</name>
                <outbound type="feature" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.B.check(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)</outbound>
                <outbound type="feature" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.B.name</outbound>
                <outbound type="feature" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.B.user_id</outbound>
                <outbound type="class" confirmed="no">java.lang.String</outbound>
            </feature>
            <feature confirmed="yes">
                <name>com.infopro.Dependency.B.name</name>
                <outbound type="class" confirmed="no">java.lang.String</outbound>
                <inbound type="feature" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.B.doStatus()</inbound>
            </feature>
            <feature confirmed="yes">
                <name>com.infopro.Dependency.B.stat</name>
                <outbound type="class" confirmed="no">java.lang.String</outbound>
                <inbound type="feature" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.B.check(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)</inbound>
            </feature>
            <feature confirmed="yes">
                <name>com.infopro.Dependency.B.user_id</name>
                <outbound type="class" confirmed="no">java.lang.String</outbound>
                <inbound type="feature" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.B.doStatus()</inbound>
            </feature>
        </class>
        <class confirmed="yes">
            <name>com.infopro.Dependency.C</name>
            <outbound type="class" confirmed="no">java.lang.Object</outbound>
            <outbound type="class" confirmed="no">javax.ejb.Remote</outbound>
            <inbound type="class" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.B</inbound>
            <feature confirmed="yes">
                <name>com.infopro.Dependency.C.doStatus()</name>
            </feature>
        </class>
    </package>
    <package confirmed="no">
        <name>java.lang</name>
        <class confirmed="no">
            <name>java.lang.Object</name>
            <inbound type="class" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.A</inbound>
            <inbound type="class" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.B</inbound>
            <inbound type="class" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.C</inbound>
            <feature confirmed="no">
                <name>java.lang.Object.Object()</name>
                <inbound type="feature" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.A.A()</inbound>
                <inbound type="feature" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.B.B()</inbound>
            </feature>
        </class>
        <class confirmed="no">
            <name>java.lang.String</name>
            <inbound type="feature" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.A.check(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)</inbound>
            <inbound type="feature" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.A.doStatus()</inbound>
            <inbound type="feature" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.A.name</inbound>
            <inbound type="feature" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.A.stat</inbound>
            <inbound type="feature" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.A.user_id</inbound>
            <inbound type="feature" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.B.check(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)</inbound>
            <inbound type="feature" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.B.doStatus()</inbound>
            <inbound type="feature" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.B.name</inbound>
            <inbound type="feature" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.B.stat</inbound>
            <inbound type="feature" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.B.user_id</inbound>
        </class>
    </package>
    <package confirmed="no">
        <name>javax.ejb</name>
        <class confirmed="no">
            <name>javax.ejb.Remote</name>
            <inbound type="class" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.C</inbound>
        </class>
        <class confirmed="no">
            <name>javax.ejb.Stateless</name>
            <inbound type="class" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.A</inbound>
            <inbound type="class" confirmed="yes">com.infopro.Dependency.B</inbound>
        </class>
    </package>
</dependencies>
```

---

XSL

```
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

```
<xsl:template match="class">
    <xsl:text></xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name"/><xsl:if test="@confirmed='no'"> *</xsl:if><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="key('cdlist','com')">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">                                                                             , </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:if test="@confirmed='no'"> *</xsl:if><xsl:text>
```

,  *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's always the XPath contains() function that you can use.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="class[contains(.//text(), 'com')]">
```